# How to define and run procedure/function using record?

Tags: delphi, function, record, procedure

I want to define record with procedure or function.
Can you help with syntax?

```
Type TRec = record
 s: string;
 p: procedure;
end;

procedure run;

Const
  Rec: TRec = ('',run);

procedure run;
begin
end;
```

It's possible to run later:

```
Rec[0].run;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (see syntax comments in code):

```
Type
  TRec = record
    s: string;
    p: procedure; // As Ken pointed out, better define a procedural type:
                  //  type TMyProc = procedure; and declare p : TMyProc;
  end;

procedure run; forward;  // The forward is needed here.
                         // If the procedure run was declared in the interface
                         // section of a unit, the forward directive should not be here.

Const
  Rec: TRec = (s:''; p:run);  // The const record is predefined by the compiler.

procedure run;
begin
  WriteLn('Test');
end;

begin
  Rec.p;  // Rec.run will not work since run is not a declared member of TRec.
          // The array index (Rec[0]) is not applicable here since Rec is not declared as an array.
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: While this is good, it's not what was asked. (Not downvoting, BTW.) The poster asked if they could assign `procedure run` to `Rec.p` and then use `Rec.run` - your code shows using `Rec.p`, which is different than what was asked.

Comment: @KenWhite, you might be right, but my example will let the OP call the run procedure through the const record Rec.

Comment: Right, but that isn't what was asked, which was "It's possible to run later: Rec[0].run;", which is *not* possible. :) No matter - the OP seems to think your solution works. (Deleting my answer and upvoting yours.)

Comment: @KenWhite, I think the question was more how to make this work from a syntax point of view.

Comment: Apparently you were right (as I said, I upvoted your answer and deleted mine).

Comment: Thanks, and I agree to your deleted answer that the `p: procedure` declaration looks awkvard. It works but the prefered way is to declare a procedure type.

Comment: Yeah, the `type` declaration thing is the only part that made me even consider not deleting mine, but yours was there first (and was accepted). :)